# Populating tableviews with data in collection view

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I need to populate data in a lot of tableviews that are in a collection view. The amount of tableviews is growing with the data coming in, which is unknown. Every tableview is in uicollectionview cell. Swiping horizontally. Currently data is being displayed in the first table and in third, and fifth and so on. And all data is the same. I want the data to only be displayed in first. And when I swipe to next table, the table displays the new data there.

**Edit:**

I can display data in **every other** tableview. And move between tableviews with the data still present, which is what I want.

It skips over every other tableview and displays data, and I don't know why!

[I can display data in the first(orange) tableview, but next data is displayed in the third(light brown), and not red.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDM9e.png)

**Update:**

There is also something weird happening with the indexPath.item:
When I am at the first cell, it print indexPath.item = 0, when I am in the middle cell it display that it indexPath.item = 2.

**Update** 
[image: As you can see the indexPath.item is different and all messed up compared to the MenuBar, I want them to have equal]

As you can see the indexPath.item is different and all messed up compared to the MenuBar, I want them to have equal

**Update**

Solved above gif problem with:

```
collectionView.isPrefetchingEnabled = false
```

Now the data is displayed correctly in the first tableview, and when I switch to next tableview the new data is displayed there, but then it duplicates so the 3rd is the same as 1st and 4th is the same as 2nd tableview.

**Update with Code:**
**MenuBar(Top Uicollectionview with cells, the circled 1,2,3..etc images)**

```
class MenuBar: UIView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
```

**NewReceiveViewController**

```
class NewReceiveViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
  var myData: [[UInt8]] = [] // will this be ReceivedArrays?
....
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  collectionView.register(ReceivedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! ReceivedCell

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray // just to see where the cell is
    cell.configure(with: myData[indexPath.row])

    return cell

 class ReceivedCell: UICollectionViewCell {
   //vars for the data
   var recievedArrays: [[UInt8]] = []  //receivedbytes array is put    into array here
   var receivedBytes: [UInt8] = []{    //receieved bytes
      didSet {
        tableView.reloadData()

      }

var data: [UInt8] = [] // will this be receieved bytes?

func configure(with data: UInt8) {

    self.data = [data]
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
}

extension ReceivedCell: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return recievedArrays.count //counting and returning how many receivedbytes arrays in receivedArrays
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tableViewCell, for: indexPath)
...
// table cells set here
// I'm a bit unsure how to set up the cell with self.data
...
return cell
```

Comment: Add some code to get a better answer.

Comment: I tried that with no prevail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55625740/one-tableview-in-up-to-25-collectionviewcells-with-all-different-data
I suspect I need to set the datasource to the tableview, but I still can't fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this by setting each cell as its own tableView's delegate.

```swift
class MyVC: UICollectionViewDataSource {

     var myData: [DataType]! // You MUST populate this value with your data before you start getting delegate calls. You should probably set this as soon as you initialize this view.

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
          // Configure collection view cell
          cell.configure(with: myData[indexPath.row]
          return cell
     }

}

class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate {

     @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
     var data: DataType!

     func configure(with data: DataType) {
          self.data = data
          self.tableView.dataSource = self
     }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
          // Set up table cell using self.data
          return cell
     }

}
```

Comment: I understand, but I dont know how many tableviews it will be. So I cant hardcode 25 table delegates and datasources. OR do you suggest to store the delegates somewhere in a multidimensional array or something. Im at the point where I could start questioning my code, but not yet. Thanks for answer man, feel free to discuss further!

Comment: Ok, I will update my answer with what I think is a good solution to your problem

Comment: I like this approach, ill test it out today! Cheers mate, this might have saved my week

Comment: Currently I have tableview functions in an extension from ReceivedCell: UIcollectionviewcell. And the RecieveViewController with  UICollectionViewController, UicollectionviewflowdelegateFlowLayout. So I can't access the tableViews variable in my tableview functions

Comment: I still can't get it to show data on the other tableviews.  Important note is that I will never know how exactly how many tableviews I need. It can be from 1 to 25. At least for now. I made a struct to be able to use the variables in both the classes.

Comment: Okay, that's even better, I'll update my answer again

Comment: I think perhaps its not showing data where I want because of the indexPath.item. Please see update with image for illustration

Comment: @wolfgang `cellForRowAt` is called long (relatively) before your cell is on screen. When you have cell 2 on screen, UIKit is going to start getting ready for 3, 4, and maybe even 5 so that they can scroll smoothly onto the screen

Comment: Yes I figured eventually! I've been trying your code @rpecka but so far I havnt been able to get it to work

Comment: The configure function.. Self.data has not been initialized. And also I get an index out of order on tableviews[index path.row] = cell.tableview.. I could update question with some of my code but I don't want to fill the whole question with code...

Comment: Ohh okay. Only use the second snippet, I will go ahead and delete the first one since it is causing confusion. The snippet is also kind of pseudocode and won't work out of the box. I will fix it to make it easier to see exactly what changes you need to make to adapt it to your code.

Comment: I've updated the answer. You were probably getting those errors because the myData property as defined before, needed to be set up on initialization, which I think doesn't work well with UIViewControllers. Now you can set it up right after initialization. If you are still having problems getting the data into the controller, you could post the code where you instantiate this controller and I could provide some guidance.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the question with as little code as possible. Its quite a lot that is happening so I just posted the essentials, hopefully I can get this to work

Comment: Ok, I see where the problem is. In my answer, `DataType` is just a placeholder for whatever the type of your data is in your program. Let's say you wanted each table view cell to show a particular string. In that case, you would change `[DataType]` in `MyVC` to `[[String]]` and change `DataType` in `MyCell` with `[String]`. By `DataType`, I did not mean that you should interact with your data on the byte level, unless that is actually what you are trying to do.

Comment: Okey, of course that make sense. I receive bytes and I cast them as strings in the labels already. So myData is sort of storing the rows for that particular tableview. If I have understood it correctly.

Comment: `myData` is a list of lists and `data` is a list. `myData` is the model for the collection view and is a set for the models of each tableView

Comment: I still get an index out of range on the cell.configure(with: myData[indexPath.item]) When I load the view that has the tableview, there is no data yet. I am sending the data manually via a Arduino over bluetooth so maybe it crashes because there is no data yet in the cells.

Comment: You need to make sure that what you return in `numberOfRowsIn` only reflects the data that you can actually produce. If your data is not available yet, then you need some placeholders that will make sense to the user.

Comment: I managed to resolve the issue. It took me a bit more work then your answer but it got me to where I wanted to be! Thanks!